# JHipster OpenAPI Model Package

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jhipster, openapi

By default, if OpenAPI is activated, JHipster creates the following apiPackage and modelPackage in the openapi-generator-maven-plugin:

```
<apiPackage>*.web.api </apiPackage>
<modelPackage>*.web.api.model </modelPackage>
```

The ArchTest checks that classes contained in the package web are neither used in the package service nor in the package repository.
How should it then be possible to use the model classes generated by OpenAPI in service methods?